# How to avoid to write the command line to compile the sass using Ruby

Tags: windows, cmd, sass

I have installed Ruby and Sass and started my work using Sass in my current project. My problem is that if command box is closed then again  I am writing everything in command box from the beginning to compile the file. Below is the code which always I need to write before start my work.

Is there any solution for this without using any app(scout/Koala/etc.)

```
C:\Users\saroj.kumar>cd ..

C:\Users>cd ..

C:\>cd xampp

C:\xampp>cd htdocs

C:\xampp\htdocs>cd "sass proj"

C:\xampp\htdocs\sass proj>cd css

C:\xampp\htdocs\sass proj\css>sass --watch test.scss:test.css
```

Comment: Don't close the console?

Comment: `cd C:\xampp\htdocs\"sass proj"\css` and `sass --watch test.scss:test.css` ?

Comment: You could make a little batch file to save you typing it out every time?